# Can not use zip from S3 for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Situation:

- I have a zip file with a JS function in a S3 bucket
- The file properties say:
  `Link: 
  https://s3.just-an-example-region-for-this-post-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/server/func-helloworld.zip`

When I create a new Lambda function and chose `Upload a .ZIP from Amazon S3` and continue I get:
`Trouble uploading file: Invalid S3 URL.`

The zip file is accessible for everyone. I can download the zip file.
I can't find a good example on how this link should look like.
I found this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=468968&#468968
But I don't understand where to get my file in a format like mentioned in the thread.

Comment: I note that you've specifed "eu-region-1" in your URL. Don't you mean eu-west-1 or eu-central-1?

Comment: The answer in the thread you linked specifically states: "You can verify the correct URL for the object by right clicking on the object in the AWS Console and selecting properties. This will display the link to the object."

Comment: @SteveRukuts it's just an example URL. The real one is different.

Comment: @mbaird That's the link I added in list item two. I can download it. Works. Without permissions. For some reason Lambda can't use it.

Did you do this before? Maybe I missed something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was fun...
S3 and Lambda need to be in the same region.
I thought just downloading a file from S3 would work no matter which region. Doesn't. Now I know.

I tried it step by step via the web console. Now that I read the [CLI docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html) it says it everywhere... damn. Should have tried the CLI first.

Comment: please share the link